# Have two teams ever played each other twice in the same world cup?

Tags: football, trivia, world-cup

In FIFA World Cup 2014, if the United States and Germany had both advanced to the final, then they would have played each other twice. This didn't happen.

But has it ever happened, that in the same World Cup, two teams have played each other both in the group stage and again in the knockout rounds?

Comment: Note that if any two teams that advance to the knock out stage from the same group won their next 3 games, they would have met in the final game.

Comment: As it is currently organised **it is impossible for two teams in the same group** to meet again **unless they both reach the final**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[1954](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_FIFA_World_Cup) - Hungary vs West Germany (group 2, final)

[1962](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_FIFA_World_Cup) - Brazil vs Czechoslovakia (group 3, final)

[1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_FIFA_World_Cup) - Poland vs Italy (group 1, semi-final)

[1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup) - Brazil vs Sweden (group B, semi-final)

[2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup) - Brazil vs Turkey (group C, semi-final)

[2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup) - Belgium vs England (group G, third place playoff)

[2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup) - Morocco vs Croatia (group F, third-place playoff)

Answer (score 3):

This is a more comprehensive answer which includes not just matches in the group and knockout stages played between 2 teams in a single edition but also match replays which were used as tie-breakers prior to the 1978 World Cup.

[1934](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1934_FIFA_World_Cup):

- Italy 1 - 1 Spain (quarter-finals), Italy 1 - 0 Spain (replay)

[1938](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1938_FIFA_World_Cup):

- Switzerland 1 - 1 Germany (round of 16), Switzerland 4 -2 Germany (replay)
- Cuba 3 - 3 Romania (round of 16), Cuba 2 - 1 Romania (replay)
- Brazil 1 - 1 Czechoslovakia (quarter-finals), Brazil 2 - 1 Czechoslovakia (replay)

[1954](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_FIFA_World_Cup):

- West Germany 4 - 1 Turkey (group 2), West Germany 7 - 2 Turkey (group stage play-off)
- Switzerland 2 - 1 Italy (group 4), Switzerland 4 - 1 Italy (group stage play-off)
- **Hungary 8 - 3 West Germany (group 2), Hungary 2 - 3 West Germany (final)**

[1958](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1958_FIFA_World_Cup):

- Northern Ireland 1 - 0 Czechoslovakia (group 1), Northern Ireland 2 - 1 Czechoslovakia (group stage play-off)
- Hungary 1 - 1 Wales (group 3), Hungary 1 - 2 Wales (group stage play-off)
- Soviet Union 2 - 2 England (group 4), Soviet Union 1 - 0 England (group stage play-off)

[1962](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_FIFA_World_Cup):

- **Brazil 0 - 0 Czechoslovakia (group 3), Brazil 3 - 1 Czechoslovakia (final)**

[1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_FIFA_World_Cup):

- **Italy 0 - 0 Poland (group 1), Italy 2 - 0 Poland (semi-finals)**

[1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup):

- **Brazil 1 - 1 Sweden (group B), Brazil 1 - 0 Sweeden (semi-finals)**

[2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup):

- **Brazil 2 - 1 Turkey (group C), Brazil 1 - 0 Turkey (semi-finals)**

[2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup):

- **Belgium 1 - 0 England (group G), Belgium - England (third place play-off)**

---

*Note: **Bold** indicates games played first in the group stage and then in the knockout stage as the original question asks.*